# Sharepoint list and access rights

Tags: security, sharepoint, sharepoint-list, access-rights

Hi I'm completely new to Sharepoint. I have a very simple application, basically a list of records. Now I need to show the records based on the user is visiting the page, I need a very simple access rights logic
Example now is

| User | Data Example |
| --- | --- |
| User1 | Row1 |
| User1 | Row2 |
| User2 | Row3 |

What I would like to have

User1 sees

| User | Data Example |
| --- | --- |
| User1 | Row1 |
| User1 | Row2 |

User2 sees

| User | Data Example |
| --- | --- |
| User2 | Row3 |

Is that possible? otherwise I prefer to develop from scratch a .NET application

Thanks in advance for your support

G.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the list view and use **[Me]** to filter your user column, like the following image:
[image]

More information: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-filtering-to-modify-a-sharepoint-view-3d8efc52-0808-4731-8f9b-3dfaeacea3d4#ID0EAABAAA=2010-2019

Please have a try and let's know if it matches your requirement.